# UITextView jumps to the bottom of the screen, behind the keyboard when frame was updated

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview

I am implementing an UITextView textInput to have a similar effect as the iOS message window, where the textview expand/shrink based on the text content.

When I update the UITextView frame in textViewDidChange function, the UITextView jumped to the bottom of the screen, and get hidden behind the keyboard. It doesn't appear in the specified frame.

Here's my code.

```
 func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView)
{
    print ("textview did changed")

    let fixedWidth : CGFloat = textView.frame.size.width
    let newSize : CGSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
    var newFrame : CGRect = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(fmaxf((Float)(newSize.width), (Float)(fixedWidth))),newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame       
}
```

Also, here's the keyboardWillAppear() and keyboardWillDisapppear() function, which is working fine

```
func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){

    print ("keyboard will appear")

    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

    let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)

    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    scrollToBottomOfTheTable()

    var messageFrame:CGRect = self.textInput.frame
    messageFrame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
    self.textInput.frame = messageFrame
}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification) {

    print ("keyboard will disappear")

    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.25)
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    UIView.commitAnimations()

    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    var messageFrame:CGRect = self.textInput.frame
    messageFrame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    self.textInput.frame = messageFrame
}
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: No im not. No xib file, im constructing all ui elements in the swift file.